# Prove that $\left\{\frac{x_{n}-y_{n}}{x_{n}+y_{n}}\right\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges, given that ...

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove that $\left\{\frac{x_{n}-y_{n}}{x_{n}+y_{n}}\right\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges, given that $\{x_{n}\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$, $\{y_{n}\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ are sequences that are increasing in $\Bbb R^+$ so that $\{x_{n}-y_{n}\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is bounded.

I apologize in advance because I'm an absolute beginner in this kind of website. If you can do this, I would be eternally grateful.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the question? And why did you tag the question with "automated theorem proving"?

Comment: I'm so sorry, I couldn't see it well

Comment: To downvoters: It is the first post of the author and his MathJax is pretty good. He had right to have no idea how to begin, because the solution seems to be a bit tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=+\infty$ then because of boundedness $\{x_n-y_n\}$ the limit is equal to 0.
2. Let both sequences are bounded. Because they are increasing, they are convergent to, say, $x$ and $y$ respectively. Hence $x_n+y_n$ tends to $x+y$ and $x_n-y_n$ to $x-y$, which ends the proof.

Comment: Just, in that case, that will be true; what happens if we don't suppose it.

Comment: @KeithCaballeroRodriguez It should be important, but I have just found an error in Remark called a while ago.